# How to set button in header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

i want to set back button in my header in react native tried many time but failed anyone help me

```
static Options = () => {
 return {
  topBar: 
 createHeader(I18n.t('settings.personal'  ), {
    component: <FontAwesome name={'arrow-left'} size={20} color={Constants.blueAccent}/>,

    onPress:  () => Navigation.popTo('SettingsStack.InitialRoute')
  })
}
```

}

Comment: What type of navigation are you using? `react-native-navigation` or `react-navigation`?

Comment: i use react-native-navigation but at this time just want to show the back button on the right side of my header